# miniconda not installing python in virtual env

Tags: python, installation, miniconda

I've recently installed miniconda and whenever I create a virtual env and try the command:

`python --version` 
I get that python isn't recognised as an internal or external command, operable prgram or batch file.
Isn't miniconda supposed to install the same Python version you used when you downloaded and installed Anaconda?

Comment: how do you create it? you have to specify what python version you want to install

Comment: I create it using ```conda create --name envname``` , don't I specify the version only if I need it to install a different version?

Comment: use: e.g. `conda create --name envname python=3.6`